# how to save only two frames from video in opencv

Tags: opencv

Actually i want to save current frame and previous frame using opencv and C++, i got this code from internet after edited this will save both frame as a current frame.

```
int main()
{
 IplImage* currFrame = 0;
 IplImage* prevFrame = 0;
 CvCapture* cap = cvCaptureFromAVI("how.mp4");
 currFrame = cvQueryFrame( cap );
 char s [20];

  prevFrame  = cvCloneImage( currFrame );

  while(currFrame = cvQueryFrame( cap ))
 {

int num = 1;
cvShowImage( "DisplayVideo", currFrame );
sprintf(s,"pics/frame%d.jpg",num);
cvSaveImage(s,currFrame);
cvNamedWindow("image1");
cvShowImage("image1",currFrame);

cvCopy( currFrame , prevFrame);
num = 2;
sprintf(s,"pics/frame%d.jpg",num);
cvSaveImage(s,prevFrame);
cvNamedWindow("image2");
cvShowImage("image2",prevFrame);

char c = cvWaitKey(500); if( c == 27 ) break;
}
 cvReleaseCapture( &cap );
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: It will help if you describe you actual problem, and post the whole code, and not just check out my code, I didn't see the whole code but I already see potential problems like "s" may not be initialized, and frankly i do not see the need to call "sprintf" since you just typed the decimal value manually a line above.

Comment: At first you are not getting two frame. You are using the same frame for both current and previous frame.Query for the next frame to get two frames.

Comment: No i am not getting, you want to say i should add precFrame=cvQueryFrame( currFrame ); below currFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer, here is the code

```
int main()
{
VideoCapture cap("how.mp4");
Mat curr, prev;
// if(!cap)return -1;
cap>>curr;
curr.copyTo(prev);
while(1)
{
  cap>>curr;
  imwrite("pics2/current.jpg",curr);
  imwrite("pics2/previous.jpg", prev);
  imshow("image1",curr);
  imshow("image2",prev);
  curr.copyTo(prev);
  if(waitKey(500)==27)break; //Esc pressed
}
}
```

Thanks to All, for your answers and support..